# Vararg in autosar c

Tags: c, autosar

Is it allowed to use varargs in an autosar C code? If not, why?

I'm not familiar with autosar. I [found](https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/adaptive/18-03/AUTOSAR_RS_CPP14Guidelines.pdf) this document for c++14, which says:

> Rule A8-4-1 (required, implementation, automated)
> Functions shall not be defined using the ellipsis notation.

The reasoning is, that the ellipsis notation bypasses the type check. It is recommended to use variadic templates, function overloading or function call chain.

I haven't found any rule regarding varargs for autosar c. Is there any rule against varargs in c code? Is there any reason to avoid it? Is there any way to avoid it (I need to implement a logging function with string formatting)?

Comment: And btw, there is already a logging component in AUTOSAR, its called DLT  (Diagnostic Log & Trace).

Answer (score 1):

It is in Misra as well. Misra C is to C as AutoSAR C++ is to C++. It improves code quality, safety, and security. Lots of stdlib things in C is unsafe. But especially strings are a lot harder without things like variable arguments.

What I do (also for logging) is to create multiple functions that is appropriate to logging in specific situations. Some thing like `log(text, int, int)` and `log(text, binary data block, size)` etc. as required. Inside these functions there is calls to single variable argument function (usually snprintf) that prints everything to the log. You are not fully compliant but you are close and the use of variable arguments is contained to a specific area of code. If you need to be fully compliant the code is decoupled and easier to change.